# Google Chrome Omnibox differences between 2 installs on Chrome 27 Dev

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, address-bar

I have Google Chrome 27 dev (specifically, 27.0.1438.7) installed on my Macbook Pro at home and my iMac at work. Both Macs are on 10.8.3.

At work my omnibox auto-completes the way I have always seen it: a menu drops down with suggestions.

However, at home I now get this:

[image]

A panel extends down.  I have gone into Chrome Flags on both and clicked "reset to defaults" and it's driving me nuts as to what is causing this behavior on only one.

Both instances sync with each other and have the same extensions.

Any ideas?

EDIT: My new tab page now looks like this too:

[image]

Comment: I thought everyone who uses dev versions of a program do it to find that kind of stuff. Just out of curiosity, what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: On my other computer, it drops a menu out of the address bar, similar to Safari and Firefox.  And the new tab page has 8 thumbnails and no search box.

I do test dev versions for this reason, I was just confused that the 2 were different on different computers.